# Is Minecraft for Raspberry Pi discontinued?

Tags: minecraft-pi-edition

In the highschool we're working with Minecraft for Raspberry Pi (also known as MCRP) to learn ruby.

I searched a little bit around the web, and I found the official page of it ([pi.minecraft.net](http://pi.minecraft.net/)) and I discovered the last post was over 3 years ago.

No post on Mojang's blog about MCRP has been posted since its announcement.
The developer of MCRP is the same of MC:PE.

Is Minecraft for Raspberry PI discontinued?

Comment: FYI http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Ghanima I don't understand you comment...

Comment: Well. You've got a Pi. Whenever you have a non-gaming question, just come over. That's all I want to say.

Comment: @Ghanima i understand your confussion: I'm asking about a ***game***, the platform of the game doesn't matters here.

Comment: There's no confusion. This was merely an informational comment to make you aware of RPi.SE just in case you'll be interested. That's all :) And in fact the platform does matter, as the game had to be ported to the Pi's ARM processor - which might also matter wrt to its continued support. But again, this was just a little pointer to the mere existance of the site, no force applied, no wish to pull this particular question over.

Comment: @Ghanima Okay, sorry, now I understand!

Comment: This is an old question; the answer has changed. See my answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, but it does not seem to be under active development.

As of 2014, it has been included in Raspbian and can be installed via:

```
sudo apt-get install minecraft-pi
```

Comment: Wow, that's new for me, I didn't knew MCRP was in Raspian! Thanks for the info! +1!

Comment: This is no longer true. Upvote other answers.

Answer (score 3):

It is no longer being updated.

I found this:

> It ded :(
> The original team has stopped supporting it and starting with 0.9 MCPE became a lot more ambitious technically, which also means that it became a lot harder to strip down to run on a Raspberry Pi. Actually, we finished removing all Pi related code to reduce complexity in 2015.
> Maybe someday we'll revisit it but I wouldn't hold my breath :P
> On the other hand, Win10 runs on the Pi so you can run the Win10 version there! ... I guess it's something

from Tommaso Checci [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Pi_Edition#Discontinuation).

The original comment on reddit can be found [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/MCPE/comments/42g9cr/is_minecraft_pi_edition_no_longer_being_developed/cza7seq/?context=3).

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but the answer as changed. This edition has been discontinued.

> Pi Edition never received any subsequent updates and is no longer updated. Despite this, it is included by default on Raspberry Pi OS (formerly Raspbian).

-- [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Pi_Edition)